# using JSON object in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

A simple and strange issue.
I have a JSON object coming from API. I want to use that JSON object to send a request to another WebService. Logically, it should work, but dont know why its not working.

JSON

```
data = {
"user": {
    "name": "first_name",
    "email": "email@example.com"
},
"comment": {
    "id": 1
}
```

}

Coffeescript

```
WebService.send
  param1: true,
  param2: false,
  param3: data
```

Note that, i have assigned my JSON object 'data' to param3 which is not working, however if do something like this, then it works

Coffeescript

```
WebService.send
  param1: true,
  param2: false,
  param3:
    user:
      name: 'first_name',
      email: 'email@example.com'
    comment:
      id: 1
```

If i pass on data like this, then it works. Does anybody know that whats the issue in assigning JSON object directly? If console.log(data), it shows the right JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATED JSON Object.

Comment: That isn't JSON but works fine here: http://jsbin.com/umiwim/1/edit

Comment: output block is balnk

Comment: Ctrl+Enter and check console or here http://jsbin.com/umiwim/3/edit

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/uZgZYWXpK check it. Why its JSON? May be i have some type here. but i am parsing like this. param3: JSON.parse(data_from_api)

Comment: I don't know what's your issue, it works for me http://i.imgur.com/wruuK0e.jpg. And that's not JSON, it's already JavaScript. JSON is _very_ specific about quotes.

Comment: right. Ctrl + Enter. Looks good, but not working in my case. In my case, it converts it like this.  IN CONSOLE:(Note the extra double qoutes around user object in param3){"param1":true,"param2":false,"param3":"{"user":{"name":"first_name","email":"email@example.com"},"comment":{"id":1}}"}

Comment: That's just the way keys are shown internally; quotes, single quotes, no quotes, it's all valid in JS but _not_ in JSON. The console output is fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your JSON data is actually parsed? I don't know how you get your data, but it looks to me as if your JSON is stored as _string_ inside of `data`, not actually parsed and stored as an _object_.

Comment: Is you `data` variable `{ data: { user: ... } }` or `{ user: ... }`?

Comment: @muistooshort: its ```code {"user":{name: 'first_name'} ...}```

Comment: Going to suggest the lazy thing as you already have a valid JavaScript object and can't get the JSON right.  Just do param3: JSON.stringify(data) when sending your request.

Assuming you aren't supporting ie7 you'll be peachy.

Comment: @zclark: Thanks man. Just tried it, but it gives an error in console. ....,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,…369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386.js 414 (Request-URI Too Long) Dont know how it appends it in the URL.

Comment: hmm dunno whats up. What does the request uri end up looking like?

Comment: http://fast.domain.com/static/concat/0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,…369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386.js 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Comment: not sure what those numbers are, but assuming they are counting up from 1, that would def make your request too long

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32058/discussion-between-nadeem-yasin-and-zclark)